# FileInfo path with '|' gives illegal characters in path exception?

Tags: c#, exception, file-io

When I try to construct a FileInfo object using a string that contains a '|' character, I'm getting an Illegal characters in path exception. The string is just parsed from some data source I don't have control over, so I can't add any escape characters to the original string. So I tried a .Replace("|","\|") on the string but still get the same exception. What's the proper way to escape this so I don't get the exception?

Also, is there a way to get the offending character in the exception so my exception handling can correct it automatically and I don't need to wait for the next magic character that isn't allowed to start crashing everything before I can handle the error?

Comment: You should provide a code sample that demonstrates the problem you're having. But the issue here is that the pipe character (`|`) is invalid for directory and file names, so you'd have to strip it out completely. The string you're getting from the data source is not a valid path.

Comment: Check against GetInvalidPathChars: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: See [Windows' reserved characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) (which you can get via the C# method Camilo mentioned)

Comment: `filePath = Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Aggregate(filePath, (fPath, chr) => fPath.Replace(chr.ToString(), ""));`...will remove all the invalid path characters from a string named `filePath`. Note that there are additional characters that are invalid for a file **name** that *are* valid for a **path**, like `: * ? \  / `.

Comment: `Path.GetInvalidPathChars().ToList().ForEach(c => filePath = filePath.Replace(c.ToString(), ""));` is another linq-y way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't sound like your data source is providing valid file paths/names for the operating system you're using.

You can use `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` and `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` to get arrays of characters that aren't allowed in a filename or path. These would need to be removed not escaped to be legal for a file system. Stripping these out is likely a work around, rather than a fix. It would be best to resolve the issue at the source of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample method that will remove invalid path characters from the path portion of the string, and invalid file characters from the file name portion of the input string:

```
public static string RemoveIllegalChars(string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) return path;

    // Remove invalid directory characters
    Path.GetInvalidPathChars().ToList()
        .ForEach(c => path = path.Replace(c.ToString(), ""));

    // Remove invalid file name characters from file name portion and return the result
    return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
        Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
            .Aggregate(Path.GetFileName(path), (fileName, invalidChar) =>
                fileName.Replace(invalidChar.ToString(), "")));
}
```